# PHP Simple Search Example

Tags: php, search

I'm learning PHP and built a little search in text file script. Here is the chain of events:

1. Opens text file
2. Creates array from each new line
3. If form is submitted, the post data is put into a function runs a regex to find the partial string or word and if matched, all entries are replaced in code with a  class around, with some CSS.

My issue is that:

If I have a sentence like:

Tom has a camera in his hand. I am also a camera on the floor.

And search for "am", it searches and finds camera, replaces this with the span class. Then it finds "am" and replaces it within Camera twice, and itself.

Here is my code:

```
    //---- Puts Array into or responds with error
    $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    if ( !is_array($lines) ) {
       echo 'Cannot create array from file';
    }

    //---- Scans and Displays Lines
    $submission = $_GET['Search'];
    function scanLines($lines, $submission) {
        foreach($lines as $line) {      
            if(strpos($line,$submission)!== false){             
                preg_match_all("/\b[a-z]*".preg_quote($submission)."[a-z]*\b/i", $line, $matches);  

                $i = 0;
                foreach($matches[$i] as $match) {   
                    $line = str_replace($match, '<span class="highlight">'.$match.'</span>', $line);
                $i++;                   
            }
            echo $line;
        }       
    }       
}
```

Direct link to example: http://www.effectivemark.com/testphp/

My question is: What is the best approach to filter out the "am" in camera, so it doesn't add the string with span tag like below:

```
    <span class="highlight">c<span class="highlight">am</span>era</span>
```

Updated code:

```
//---- Scans and Displays Lines
$submission = $_GET['Search'];
function scanLines($lines, $submission) {
    foreach($lines as $line) {      
        if(strpos($line,$submission)!== false){ 

            $words = explode(' ', $line);
            $i = 0;
            $combine = array();
            foreach($words as $word) {
                if (preg_match("/\b[a-z]*".preg_quote($submission)."[a-z]*\b/i", $word)) {
                    preg_match_all("/\b[a-z]*".preg_quote($submission)."[a-z]*\b/i", $word, $match);
                    $matches = '<span class="highlight">' . $match[0][0] . '</span>';
                }
                else { 
                    $matches = $word;
                }
                array_push($combine, $matches);
            $i++;
            }

            foreach($combine as $combined) {
                echo $combined . ' ';
            }
        }       
    }       
}
```

Comment: you can get words in line by explode(), or, maybe better, get them with: http://php.net/manual/sr/function.str-word-count.php, and mach whole words, rather than word part.

Comment: So put words into array, and run this match for all words? Let me give it a try

Comment: yes, i wouldn't even use regex, you can check if get value is in_array()?

Comment: The regex accounts for any word partially typed. So typing 'app' in the word "Apple" will get that full value.

Comment: I wrote the array of line formation as: $words = explode(' ', $line); However, if I run the regex for each, I cannot seem to get the logic right. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better divide lines into words ,It'll make easy to match them

Comment: Yup. You  could define "word" as `a-Z0-9'"`

Comment: Or just divide String in chars,then retrieve it them till ' '|','|'.'|';'|':' occurs.you'll have a word then just match it with users input,if matched then print the string (line).

Comment: I used: $words = explode(' ', $line); and this put each word into a string of the array, however I am unsure how to process this, and have it parse the original line. Do I just have it find the word, str_replace with <span> class, and turn the array back into a sentence?

Comment: Check out updated code. This worked great. I figured the remaining parts myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be ok:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    <h4>Search Object In Text File:</h4>
    <input type="text" name="search" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php
        $filename="tekst.txt";
        $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

        if ( !is_array($lines) ) {
            echo 'Cannot create array from file';
        }

        //---- Scans and Displays Lines

        if(isset($_POST['search']))    
$submission = $_POST['search'];
        scanLines($lines,$submission);

        function scanLines($lines, $submission) {
            foreach($lines as $line) {
                $word_arr=str_word_count($line,1);
                $length=count($word_arr);
                for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++) {

                    if(preg_match("#$submission#",$word_arr[$i],$match)) {
                        $word_arr[$i]='<span class="highlight">'.$word_arr[$i].'</span>';
                        $new_line=implode(' ',$word_arr);
                        echo $new_line.'<br>';
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        ?>
```

So, if you want to search FOR ANY PART OF THE WORD, and highlight whole word, rather than just matched part. For complete (more rigid) whole word search, you can just use simple in_array() function.

Comment: I figured the issue out, look at updated code. Thanks though!